# Use .Net-Repeater with jquery

Tags: jquery, .net, repeater

I have a Repeater (ASP.Net).

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cb" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

I would like to write Text in the text-box if I click on the checkbox, using jQuery. Is this possible and how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend simply using a CSS class and using that to identify the TextBox:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cb" CssClass="repCheck" />
  </ItemTemplate>
```

And then:

```
$('.repCheck').change(function(){
    // via Andre
    $(this).siblings('input[type="text"]').first().val("clicked");
});
```

Comment: what if i am having multiple text boxes... and i want to change values of each?

Comment: @RonakBhatt That sounds like a separate question :)

Comment: @RonakBhatt - Comments aren't intended for converstaion, but you can simply access multiple inputs from within the checkbox change handler. If they are different, you can narrow the selector using a class.

Comment: thanx @rechard.... Actully i was assuming the same output.. but was not confident over it..

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to post the html output to get a working code, but it is something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#<%=rep.ClientID  %> input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
        $(this).change(function(){
            $(this).siblings('input[type="text"]').first().val("clicked");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. One possibility is the approach by the server:

On the Load Event (in the server) of the CheckBox, you can do the following:

```
void checkBox_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) sender;
     TextBox txt = (TextBox) chk.Parent.FindControl("txt");
     chk.Attributes.Add("onclick",
                          string.Format("$(\"#{0}\").val('{1}');", txt.ClientID, "newValue");
}
```

**EDIT:** It was missing the # in the jQuery selector.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can use the ID selector to select the DOM elements with the ID="txt" that you have specified. http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

You can then update the .text() attribute of those elements. http://api.jquery.com/text/

Something like this should work in the simplest fashion:

```
$("#txt").text("some new text");
```

Comment: In a Repeater, the actual `id` property will have an autogenerated value.